# Can you host Web API and ServiceStack on same root route?

Tags: telerik, servicestack, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a third party Reporting tool (telerik) that uses Web API services to provide reporting services.  The path to the reporting services begins with api/, I can get either ServiceStack or Telerik to operate separately or together if they are on different paths, but is it possible to have them on the same path using IgnoreRoute so that the route is ignored by the Web API service and handled by ServiceStack?  I would like to have something like api/reports for Telerik and api/rest for ServiceStack.  I'm sure there is some technical reason why this is not possible but would like to know why.